# jQuery hover does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

Folks, why jQuery hover does not work?
Here is the link - http://layot.prestatrend.com/ Thanks for any reply!
Here is the code:

```
$('.product_image').hover(
  function () {
    $('.product_right_block').show(100);
  },
  function () {
    $('.product_right_block').hide(100);
  }
);
```

Comment: please provide the code you suspect to be the issue

Comment: what exactly isn't working? which element is supposed to change on hover?

Comment: don't link to an image of code, either show us code, or a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your javascript in the middle of the page and did not encase it in a document ready. So the code never binds to the specified elements. Try and be much more descriptive when asking a question. We shouldn't have to find what file the javascript code is in nor guess based on your code what you need to hover over and is supposed to be shown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
 $('.product_image').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).children('.product_right_block').show(100);
      },
      function () {
        $(this).children('.product_right_block').hide(100);
      }
    );
});
</script>
```

Don't make script calls in the middle of your page. Declare them in head or in an external javascript file. This makes finding and debugging code easier and also helps prevent simple mistakes like this.

Comment: Thanks, man, it's work! But there is another question sorry for my noob - when I hover on image all blocks are shown - please, look it here - http://layot.prestatrend.com/ - is there a way to show only one block over the image I am hovering? Thanks!

Comment: @Anton - see my updated answer. That's because your selector `$('.product_right_block')` says to get everything with that class. You only want the one that is inside the hovered element. So use `children` to select it.

Comment: mrtsherman, thank you very much! Also I found that 'find' insted of 'children' also works - what do you think the best to use or there is no difference?

Comment: @Anton: The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in `(document).ready()`. Your hover code actually worked fine, without any problems.

Please see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CAca7/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 $('.product_image').hover(
      function () {
        $('.product_right_block').show(100);
      },
      function () {
        $('.product_right_block').hide(100);
      }
    );
});
```

Comment: Yes, thank, bro above has answered already but there is another question - when I hover on image all blocks are shown - please, look it here - layot.prestatrend.com - is there a way to show only one block over the image I am hovering? Thanks!